# Micromax A120 softbricked after using a repartition app

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, partitions

I have a Micromax A120 with stock Kitkat.

I rooted it and used "mprio repartition" app to increase the app installation space and the screen displayed:

> Partition is ready please boot into recovery and clear cache and data/factory reset

So I did that. Now when I try to power on the device it shows Micromax logo and then an Android logo, and a line indicating that a task is being performed.

This has been happening for almost 2 hrs so I removed the battery.

I decided to flash stock ROM  using [SP Flash tools](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool), but when I connect the device using the USB cable it shows only the charging light and is not detected in PC.

What should I do?

Comment: This might be a silly question, given that MediaTek devices such as your Micromax A120 aren't supposed to have this mode, but are you able to boot into [fastboot mode?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2185683)

Comment: Did you create a backup of any kind?

Comment: What is this "mprio repartition" app? Please mention a link for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem on my mediatek device.

**Solution**

- Pull out battry
- Go to recovery mode.
- And Just restore the nandroid **BACKUP** you have made. (Hope you have made the backup)